# Statement of purpose: how to give motivations for applying to a certain graduate school without stating the obvious or gratuitous flattery?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, statement-of-purpose

In a statement of purpose (for graduate admission, in mathematics), how can one address the question of "why do you want to attend this university?"  without making it sound like I'm stating the obvious or giving out gratuitous flattery?

In paticular, for reference's sake, I'd be interested in reading some sample statements where this issue is addressed smoothly.

Answer (score 10):

This could be a good opportunity to mention particular faculty there you might want to work with, if there are any such. (But don't go overboard, or say anything that's not true.) In any case, in my experience, these sections generally don't affect decisions -- with the one big exception that if you say you want to come to study geometry, and the committee knows that all 3 geometers in the department are retiring, they might not admit you for your own sake. (Another reason not to say anything that's not true!)

Answer (score 2):

Riku, this is a key question.  They want to know if you are applying to them because you were told that it's a good idea, which means you may not apply yourself to the studies, or if you are eager for what they have to give you.  So tell them why it has to be them, and not some second rate establishment out in nowhereville.

Something along these lines will not go amiss: "*I will benefit from the unique situation that MIT offers.  In particular I look forward attending the lectures of Dr X, and also the opportunites to enjoy the cross fertilization of ideas with students of other disciplines, such as  ... and ...*"  Try to find 4 or 5 reasons that are about why this university, and this university only, is the one that will inspire you to achieve more than any other.  It's OK for one of them to be a social reason, if it's one that the reader will identify with, such as "*I want to join the chess club*" or "*New Orleans has the best sea food restaurants in the world*".

Obviously at the interview they will ask you justify what you put in this section, so make sure you can do that.

You will come across this question again and again in your life.  I have been in the interviewer's seat and I ask it for the same reason.  If you answer this well, I am more likely to hire you than the person who says "yours is the best place".

Finally a warning - if I get a good answer to a question, I google the wording to see if its genuine or plagiarised.  So don't copy answers off the 'net.

Best of luck with your endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

Stating some courses they offer is a great way to show them that you have done your research before your application. If that course is unique, then that might add extra value. For example, suppose you want to apply to the University of Michigan, with a specific interest in electromagnetics. Then mention some courses such as the '**EECS 526: Plasmonics**' is a course you look forward to taking. In this way, you can demonstrate the committee that you really want to attend this school.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a trick question. There is some reason you're applying to this school: what is it?

- If this is a top school in your field, you should not pretend you're unaware of this. Instead, say something like "It should be clear why someone with my background would be drawn to MIT. Some of the most interesting research in mathematics is happening at MIT, in particular [blah]. I am also excited by the high caliber of the other students."
- If the true reason is location, I would again be honest; they are going to notice that you are local and infer your real reason anyway. For example "Since I am married with children, remaining in Seattle is non-negotiable. I am fortunate that U. Washington has...[other reasons / good qualities here]."
- You can mention specific professors, but bear in mind that the professor you list may well read your application. As others have said, being too specific (I want to work with Dr. X) can cause problems if you are dishonest.
- Most universities have some program (e.g., interdisciplinary studies, community outreach, etc.) -- mentioning this is maybe a good idea, but again be honest; simple statements ("I also read that Nebraska has a collaborative with Nebraska State; this seems like a good idea") are more endearing than over the top statements ("I am extremely passionate about inter-university relationships; networking with my peers at Nebraska State will present a superlative opportunity for my professional growth.")
- Finally, there is no need to go overboard on this section. A short paragraph where you state some fairly obvious reasons is fine -- it is your potential to complete a good PhD that really matters; here they just want to see that you have put some thought into this.

One last comment. Don't write anything you wouldn't feel comfortable saying out loud in a one-on-one conversation. Too many of these essays have cringy, boring stories about the author's childhood, or dreams, or identity, etc. You are a professional making a professional decision to apply to this university: here you should state your professional reasons why you are doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to ask this question, the answer may be that you don't need to address this question. Obviously, if there are specific faculty you believe you want to work with then you can mention that and why you want to work with them. But if you can replace the university name in what you write with a different university and it is still true then I'm not really sure you need to write anything about the university at all.

Instead I would focus on what experiences you've had that make you think you are interested in pursuing math research and anything unique about your educational history that schools may not know just by looking at your transcript.

As someone who recently went through the application process for math PhD programs, I did not mention specific reasons why I wanted to attend a specific program in my statements.